# json.net vs DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, json, json.net

I know there's a DataContractJsonSerializer that comes now with the .net framework and is used by wcf ajax enabled services. However, I've noticed there's also a json.net project over at [codeplex](http://json.codeplex.com/).
I'm wondering if there are any advantages or features that are present in the codeplex project that are missing from the .net framework.

Comment: I would actually look at the MS [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) (in System.Web.Extensions.dll) before `DataContractJsonSerializer` - far more "typical" output, IMO

Comment: Microsoft has adopted the open source Json.NET library for ASP.NET MVC 4 and ASP.NET WebApi: [ASP.NET MVC, Web API, Razor and Open Source](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/03/27/asp-net-mvc-web-api-razor-and-open-source.aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

json.net has next pros:

- Control over how dates get formatting (the `\/Date(123)\/` MS AJAX style)
- The ability to serialize object graphs that contain cycles (by telling Json.NET to ignore them)

There are a lot of explanation how its reflects on WCF developing [here](http://samscode.com/index.php/2010/06/entity-framework-v4-end-to-end-application-strategy-part-3-changes-to-data-layer/).

Also, regarding to http://banachowski.com/deprogramming/2010/08/json-net-vs-net-datacontractjsonserializer/ it has better performance, but this results can be argued.

Answer (score 4):

I have used `DataContractSerializer` and `JavaScriptSerializer` and I love them. However JSON.Net is quite more feature rich and was available long before .NET had such features.

Comment: two things: a. can you expand on the "More Feature Rich" part.b. So was json.net simply a solution for a time when .net didn't support json natively?

Comment: Even when .net did support it, JSON.NET did it noticably faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a full feature comparison in the Json.Net documentation:

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm